# Objects into JSON decoder through Elm ports

Tags: elm

I am passing an array of objects via ports into my Elm app. An example of an one of the objects in the array is:

```js
{
    FullName: 'Foo Bar',
    Location: 'Here'
}
```

As you can see the keys in the object start with a capital, so I need to decode these in Elm. In my Elm code I have a `type` for the `Person`

```elm
type alias Person =
    { fullName : String
    , location : String
    }
```

and the port:

```elm
port getPeople : (List Json.Decode.Value -> msg) -> Sub msg
```

Finally I have a decoder (I am using [Elm Decode Pipeline](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/NoRedInk/elm-decode-pipeline)) to parse the data into the `Person` type.

```elm
peopleDecoder : Decoder Person
peopleDecoder =
    decode Person
        |> required "FullName" string
        |> required "Location" string
```

My question is how do I map the incoming port data into the `Person` type? I know I could do this in JS but I'd rather do it in my Elm code.

Comment: What is`Worker` in your example `peopleDecoder`?

Comment: That was a typo, fixed now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`Json.Decode.decodeValue`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.0.0/Json-Decode#decodeValue) can decode a `Json.Decode.Value`, but it returns a `Result String (List Person)`.

If you defined your Msg like this:

```elm
type Msg
    = GetPeople (Result String (List Person))
```

You could set up your subscription like this:

```elm
port getPeople : (Json.Decode.Value -> msg) -> Sub msg

subscriptions : Model -> Sub Msg
subscriptions model =
    getPeople (GetPeople << decodeValue (list peopleDecoder))
```

(Note that the first argument in the port has been changed to just a `Value` instead of `List Value`)